# Rails - Add style/image to button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, stylesheet

I'm developing in rails right now and I was wondering if there are any easy ways to add some style to the button_to control.

Can you add styling to the

```
 <%= submit_tag 'Log in' %>
```

or

```
 <%= button_to "Show Me", {:controller => 'personal', :action => "add" } %>
```

It would be great to change the color....But brownie point if someone can tell me how to make it an image

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you're using an image, there is no reason to use `button_to` instead of `link_to`, "button look" will be lost to the user.  You can create an image with a link like so:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png"), {:controller => 'foo', :action => "bar" } %>
```

If, for some reason, you **need** to use button_to, you can give it a CSS class and apply some styles via that:

```
 <%= button_to "Show Me", {:controller => 'personal', :action => "add" }, {:class => "buttonTo" } %>
```

Comment: Is this because each tag accepts an `html_options` hash as a last parameter? This is stuck in my head for some reason.

Comment: That's correct! The last hash that is passed in is basically converted into properties directly on the resultant DOM node. Here you can specify classes, custom IDs, or inline styles. You can also add data attributes which can be read by your JS!

Answer (score 6):

In addittion to Mike's very fine pointer to using a pre-defined `:class`, you can also go for `:style` and define the CSS inline. Helps a great deal if you want to define your style on the fly:

`<%= button_to "Show Me", {:controller => 'personal', :action => "add" }, {:style => "background: #{obj.colourname}" } %>`

(With `obj` being some model instance that stores some HTML colour value at the `colourname` attribute.)